# How to get azure tenant location and subdomain name

Tags: azure

I have logged in to my azure dev account and can see the tenant location as,

United States datacenters

How can I get the code of this location? for example uksouth, uswest2.

Also how can I get the subdomain name of my tenant.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some information in Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory.

On Overview you get the primary domain, and in Properties you get the Country and Data Location.

You can find in [this page](https://msit.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiODdjOWViZDctMWRhZS00ODUzLWI4MmQtNWM5NjBkZTBkNjFlIiwidCI6IjcyZjk4OGJmLTg2ZjEtNDFhZi05MWFiLTJkN2NkMDExZGI0NyIsImMiOjV9) the location of a specific AAD service depending on your configured country.

Answer (score 0):

to get all the US datacenters, you can use this (after authenticating to azure):

```
Get-AzLocation | ? {$_.displayName -match ".* us.*$"} | ft location, displayName
```